# Docusign update sdk method

Tags: methods, docusignapi

Please help me in DocuSign update /resend method. Share the input paramters need to passed for node update method. I'm getting response as bad request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean this method:

```
this.update = function(accountId, envelopeId, optsOrCallback, callback)
```

The parameters are:

- @param {String} accountId The external account number (int) or account ID Guid.
- @param {String} envelopeId The envelopeId Guid of the envelope being accessed.
- @param {Object} optsOrCallback Optional parameters, if you are passing no optional parameters, you can either pass a null or omit this parameter entirely.
- @param {String} optsOrCallback.advancedUpdate When set to **true**, allows the caller to update recipients, tabs, custom fields, notification, email settings and other envelope attributes.
- @param {String} optsOrCallback.resendEnvelope When set to **true**, sends the specified envelope again.
- @param {module:model/Envelope} optsOrCallback.envelope
- @param {module:api/EnvelopesApi~updateCallback} callback The callback function, accepting three arguments: error, data, response
- data is of type: {@link module:model/EnvelopeUpdateSummary}